# Spring boot WebLogic 12c Jndi Datasource

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, jndi, weblogic12c

I'm deploying a Spring boot application on WebLogic 12c.

Without Jndi datasource all works fine.
I tried to configure on WebLogic a datasource with name "jdbc/MyDataSource" and on my application I setted the propertie like that:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/MyDataSource
```

But, when I deploy my web app I receive the following error:

> weblogic.application.ModuleException:
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup
>   'jdbc.MyDataSource' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved '';
>   remaining name 'jdbc/MyDataSource'

I tried also the following properties configuration without success:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource

spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/jdbc/MyDataSource

spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jdbc/MyDataSource
```

My maven configuration:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

My Spring App Configuration:

```
@EnableSwagger2

@ComponentScan({ "com.ws.repository", "com.ws.service", "com.ws.controller" })

@EntityScan("com.ws.entity")

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ws.repository")

public class MyServiceApplication {
...
}
```

Expected:

I want to use the same jndi datasource because I want to deploy many services that use just one datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved modifying the servers destination (all, including AdminServer) of the datasource and saving the configuration

Comment: can you please share more details on the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [default DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/jdbca/default_datasource.html#GUID-EE3DAF88-3D79-4271-803E-A288ECEE211D), and set the lookup name(*java:comp/DefaultDataSource*), and check if it works.

I have [an example using Spring with Wildfly](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/jakartaee), all JNDI names(Datasource, JMS, Java Mail, EntityManagerFactory, etc) are working well.